# Is the php syntax wrong?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

**The result is a blank screen.**

**php&Javascript code**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_passwd,$db_name);

if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
  echo "no database  " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");

$result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from Market");

$n = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
  var positions = [
      {
          latlng: new daum.maps.LatLng(
            <?= $row['lat']; ?>, <?= $row['lon']; ?>
          )
      }
<?php $n++;
}
?>
```

**Normal code when latitude and longitude are inserted without using mysql**

```
var positions = [
    {
        latlng: new daum.maps.LatLng(33.450705, 126.570677)
    }
];
```

The error message is not displayed in the result window and a blank screen is displayed.

Comment: The code is done in the script.

Comment: Is there any data in the `Market` table? Or is it placed in the `script` tag?

Comment: There is a market table in mysql.

Comment: If you are concerned about the PHP syntax, `run php -l ` on the file and it will tell you if there are syntax errors.

Comment: you have not echo any output.

Comment: So is there any **data** in the `Market` table?

Comment: var positions = [
      {
          latlng: new daum.maps.LatLng(
            <?= $row['lat']; ?>, <?= $row['lon']; ?>
          )
      }]. try to close position table with  ].

Comment: Please share your Market table structure

Answer (score 0):

- Add this in the beginning of the your php code

`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

- Make sure there is at least one row in Market table.
- Add `var_dump(mysqli_error($con));` after *mysqli_query*  and make
  sure there is no error.

Comment: No error message is output.

Comment: in the last line of the php just write `echo 'ok';`  I want to see if your php runs all the way.